# How can I use pyqgis to automate a series of field calculations?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've got a shapefile with about 30 fields that I'll need to update from time to time by importing a CSV with new data, joining it to the shapefile, and using the field calculator to carry the new values into the old fields one at a time:

[image]

However, this is a tedious process, and it seems like something ripe for automation with pyQGIS. The target field names and corresponding join field names will not change over time.

I have a sense of what this would look like in SQL, but the python version escapes me, and [this documentation](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html) is thin on field calculation.

Is it even possible to automate a batch of field calculations like this?

Comment: So it's just the update that you want to script?

Comment: Exactly; string together multiple updates. And the schema will be the same every time, just the values will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ultimate destination of this file was PostGIS, I moved the process to a SQL script. It'd be nice to know how to do this with pyqgis, but no longer necessary for my purpose.

Comment: You could try using a model in the Processing Toolbox

Comment: Good call, but I was hoping to see code :)